# Send JSON response from Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add controller in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, controllers, plugin, wishlist, json

I am trying to override `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add` controller's execute() method to return a JSON response.

I have created a after plugin for it.

Vendor\Company\etc\frontend\di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add">
    <plugin name="vendorCompanyExtension" type="Vendor\Company\Plugin\Index\Add" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Company\Plugin\Index\Add.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Company\Plugin\Index;

class Add 
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_jsonHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    ) {
        $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add $subject, $result) 
    {

        $newResult = [];

        $newResult["message"] = "Hello";

        $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($newResult)
        );

        return $result;

    }
}
```

In the original `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add.php`, there is a code:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*', ['wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()]);
        return $resultRedirect;
```

I am trying to return a JSON response instead of redirecting to a Wishlist page after a product is added to the wishlist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Add
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory */
    protected $_jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->_jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
    ) {
        return $this->_jsonFactory->create()->setData(['message' => 'Hello']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a correct way? I think afterExecute() should return a data.

Comment: If I remove the return then when a customer is not logged in and he clicks on the wishlist link then it does not redirect to the login page.

Comment: It's really strange issue, which I can't reproduce. Authentication passes through plugin on `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\AbstractIndex` (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/etc/di.xml#L21-L23). The plugin processes `beforeDispatch` method (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Controller/Index/Plugin.php#L63), and set `no-dispatch` flag if user not authorized. Method `execute` in controllers don't runs if the flag is set (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php#L105).

Comment: So, your plugin on `execute` method doesn't affect on authorization process

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: But as you said remove return statement from the plugin. Is it correct?

Comment: If we remove the return statement then it properly sends the JSON response from afterExecute() plugin. But if a customer is not logged in and clicks on the wishlist then we have removed return statement so it does not work correctly i.e. it does not redirect to log in page.

Comment: Why? Plugin not affect on authorization, I explained this above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73768/discussion-between-vedu-and-evgeny-levinsky).